# How can I define an async method in a trait?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a trait that I'm using to abstract away `tokio::net::TcpStream` and `tokio::net::UnixStream`:

```
/// Interface for TcpStream and UnixStream.
trait TryRead {
  // overlapping the name makes it hard to work with
  fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error>;
}

impl TryRead for TcpStream {
  fn do_try_read(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize, std::io::Error> {
      self.try_read(buf)
  }
}
```

The problem is that I want to abstract away `pub async fn readable(&self) -> io::Result<()>` in both methods but async methods cannot be implemented in traits. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On stable Rust, `async fn` cannot be used in traits. There is ongoing work that will make this possible in the future, but the easiest solution currently is to use the [`async-trait`](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait) crate:

```rust
#[async_trait]
trait Readable {
    async fn readable(&self) -> io::Result<()>;
}

#[async_trait]
impl Readable for Reader {
    async fn readable(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        do_stuff().await
    }
}
```

To avoid having `Send` bound placed on the `async` trait methods, you can invoke the async trait macro as `#[async_trait(?Send)]` on both the trait and the impl blocks.

### `#![feature(async_fn_in_trait)]`

On nightly, it is now possible to write async trait methods using the `async_fn_in_trait` feature:

```rust
#![feature(async_fn_in_trait)]

trait Readable {
    async fn readable(&self) -> io::Result<()>;
}


impl Readable for Reader {
    async fn readable(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        do_stuff().await
    }
}
```

However, the current implementation is limited, and does not allow specifying `Send` or `Sync` bounds on the returned future. See the [announcement post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2022/11/17/async-fn-in-trait-nightly.html) for details.

### Associated Types

Another way of doing it is with an associated type:

```rust
trait Readable {
    type Output: Future<Output = io::Result<()>>;

    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output;
}
```

When implementing this trait, you can use any type that implements `Future`, such as `Ready` from the standard library:

```rust
use std::future;

impl Readable for Reader {
    type Output = future::Ready<io::Result<()>>;
    
    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output {
        future::ready(Ok(()))
    }
}
```

`async` functions return an opaque `impl Future`, so if you need to call one inside your function, you can't have a concrete `Output` type. Instead, you can return an dynamically typed `Future`:

```rust
impl Readable for Reader {
    // or use the handy type alias from the futures crate:
    // futures::BoxFuture<'static, io::Result<()>>
    type Output = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<()>>>>;
    
    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Box::pin(async {
            do_stuff().await
        })
    }
}
```

Note that using these trait methods will result in a heap allocation and dynamic dispatch per function-call, just like with the async-trait crate. This is not a significant cost for the vast majority of applications, but is something to be considered.

### Capturing References

One issue that may come up is the fact that the associated type `Output` does not have a lifetime, and therefore cannot capture any references:

```rust
struct Reader(String);

impl Readable for Reader {
    type Output = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<()>>>>;
    
    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("{}", self.0);
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
16 |       fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output {
   |                   - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
17 | /         Box::pin(async move {
18 | |             println!("{}", self.0);
19 | |             Ok(())
20 | |         })
   | |__________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Associated types on stable Rust cannot have lifetimes, so you would have to restrict the output to a boxed future that captures from self to make this possible:

```rust
trait Readable {
    // note the anonymous lifetime ('_) that refers to &self
    fn readable(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<()>> + '_>>;
}

impl Readable for Reader {
    fn readable(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = io::Result<()>> + '_>> {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("{}", self.0);
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

This is actually exactly what the `async-trait` crate does under the hood.

### Unstable Features

If you are on nightly, the story is better. You can enable the `type_alias_impl_trait` feature and use regular `async/await` syntax without boxing:

```rust
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

trait Readable {
    type Output: Future<Output = io::Result<()>>;

    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output;
}


impl Readable for Reader {
    type Output = impl Future<Output = io::Result<()>>;
    
    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output {
        async { ... }
    }
}
```

The borrowing issue still applies with the above code. However, with the recently stabilized generic associated type feature, you make `Output` generic over a lifetime and capture `self`:

```rust
trait Readable {
    type Output<'a>: Future<Output = io::Result<()>>;

    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output<'_>;
}
```

And the previous example compiles, with zero boxing!

```rust
struct Reader(String);

impl Readable for Reader {
    type Output<'a> = impl Future<Output = io::Result<()>> + 'a;
    
    fn readable(&self) -> Self::Output<'_> {
        Box::pin(async move {
            println!("{}", self.0); // we can capture self!
            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `async-trait` can avoid the `Send` bound by using `#[async_trait(?Send)]` on the trait and implementations

Comment: tokio::net::TcpStream::readable() returns io::Result<()> and when I try your first snippets I fail with the error "the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type".

Comment: @ruipacheco I mentioned this in my answer: "In cases where you can't statically type your result, you can return an owned dynamically typed Future"

Comment: I've refactored my code to use async_trait but still have the same problem.

Comment: @ruipacheco are you `.awaiting` the future?

Comment: In my calling code, yes. Should I do it within the new trait?

Comment: rust-analyzer was giving me the wrong output, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, it is not possible to use [`async` methods in traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62149). While that feature gets stabilized (and it will probably take quite some time), the only solution I know is the `async_trait` crate.

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[async_trait]
trait Readable {
    fn async readable(&self) -> io::Result<()>;
}
```

The `async_trait` macro basically just turn your function into the following code:

```rust
trait Readable {
    fn readable<'a>(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn 'a + Send + Future<Output = io::Result<()>>>
}
```

The downside of this method is the additional cost of a trait object.

Comment: async-trait turns your function into a `Pin<Box<dyn Future<...>>>` with a `Send` bound

Comment: Can someone update the example for future reference?

Comment: Yep, done, thanks for pointing that out. I was pretty sure I remembered how the code was expanded

Answer (score 0):

According to a recent post: https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2022/11/17/async-fn-in-trait-nightly.html. I think we could take a shot in 1.67.0-nightly (2022-11-17).

edit:

I make a sample here: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/489285f2cfefdcc4849d2ff1ad370ce3

Comment: So this is "I read about something which might help, but I never tried it." ? Could you try for [answer]?

Comment: Sorry about that. I noticed the article had a playground sample there, so I didn't create my own. I just provide my own sample here, thanks ur remind.

Comment: What you added is only a link, which is not considered a contribution to an answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick update: The [`async_fn_in_trait` pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/115822) has been merged, and should be in stable rust by version 1.75, due for release on the 28th December 2023. See the pull request for full details of what this PR enables. In short, you'll be able to do this (code example taken from the PR):

```rust
trait Bar {
    async fn bar(self);
}

impl Bar for () {
    async fn bar(self) {}
}
```