# How do I await a future inside a non-async method which was called from an async method within the context of a Tokio runtime?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

I'm using Tokio 1.1 to do async things. I have an `async` `main` with `#[tokio::main]` so I'm already operating with a runtime.

`main` invokes a non-async method where I'd like to be `await` on a future (specifically, I'm collecting from a datafusion dataframe). This non-async method has a signature prescribed by a trait which returns a struct, not a `Future<Struct>`. As far as I'm aware, I can't mark it async.

If I try and call `df.collect().await;`, I get the

> only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks

error from the compiler, pointing out that the method that I'm calling `await` within is not `async`.

If I try and `block_on` the future from a new runtime like this:

```rust
tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
    .build()
    .unwrap()
    .block_on(df.collect());
```

I get a runtime panic:

> Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.

If I try `futures::executor::block_on(df.collect()).unwrap();`, I get a new runtime panic:

> 'not currently running on a Tokio 0.2.x runtime.'

which is weird because I'm using Tokio v1.1.

This feels harder than it should. I'm within an async context, and it feels like the compiler should know that and allow me to call `.await` from within the method - the only code path invokes this method from within an `async` block. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: `awaiting` inside a sync functions just doesn't fundamentally work. You can spawn a blocking task with `tokio::spawn_blocking`.

Comment: @Shepmaster My not-async method has a signature prescribed by a trait, and which returns a struct, not a Future<Struct>. As far as I'm aware, I can't mark it async. I'll take a closer look at that other q, and update the original if there's a difference. I think I tried thread::spawn, but can't quite remember why that was problemsome.

Comment: @Ibraheem don't think I saw `spawn_blocking` , I'll take a look and update. Thanks!

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed - spawn_blocking seems to return a `JoinHandle` which still needs to be `await`-ed - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228958/discussion-between-shepmaster-and-ibraheem-ahmed).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I'm within an async context, and it feels like the compiler should know that and allow me to call .await from within the method

It is fundamentally impossible to `await` inside of a synchronous function whether or not you are within the context of a runtime. `await`'s are transformed into yield points, and `async` functions are transformed into state machine's that make use of these yield points to perform asynchronous computations. Without marking your function as `async`, this transformation is impossible.

If I understand your question correctly, you have the following code:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {};
    foo.bar()
}

impl Trait for Foo { 
    fn bar(df: DataFrame) -> Vec<Data> {
        df.collect().await
    }
}
```

The issue is that you cannot await `df.collect` from within `bar`, because it is not marked as `async`. If you can modify the signature of `Trait`, then you can make `Trait::bar` an async method with the workarounds mentioned in [How can I define an async method in a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921581/how-to-implement-async-method-in-trait/65924807#65924807).

If you cannot change the signature of `Trait`, then you have a problem. Async functions should **never** spend a long time without reaching a `.await`. As explained in [What is the best approach to encapsulate blocking I/O in future-rs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932137/what-is-the-best-approach-to-encapsulate-blocking-i-o-in-future-rs), you can to use `spawn_blocking` when transitioning into non-async code:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {};
    tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || foo.bar()).await
}

impl Trait for Foo { 
    fn bar(df: DataFrame) -> Vec<Data> {
        df.collect().await
    }
}
```

Now you need a way to run `df.collect` to completion, without awaiting. You mentioned that you tried to create a nested runtime to solve this problem:

> If I try and block_on the future from a new runtime ... I get a panic

However, tokio does not allow you create nested runtimes. You *could* create a new, *independent* runtime, as explained in [How can I create a Tokio runtime inside another Tokio runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536566/how-can-i-create-a-tokio-runtime-inside-another-tokio-runtime-without-getting-th). However, spawning a nested runtime would be inefficient.

Instead of spawning a new runtime, you can get a handle to the *current* runtime:

```rust
let handle = Handle::current();
```

Enter the runtime context:

```rust
handle.enter();
```

And then run the future to completion with `futures::executor::block_on`:

```rust
impl Trait for Foo { 
    fn bar(df: DataFrame) -> Vec<Data> {
        let handle = Handle::current();
        handle.enter();
        futures::executor::block_on(df.collect())
    }
}
```

Entering the tokio runtime context will solve the error you were getting previously:

> If I try futures::executor::block_on(df.collect()).unwrap();, I get a new runtime panic `not currently running on a Tokio 0.2.x runtime`

I would urge you to try and avoid doing this if you can. The optimal solution would be to mark `Trait::bar` as `async` and `await` as normal. Any other solutions, including the ones mentioned above, involve blocking the current thread until the given future completes.

*Credit @AliceRyhl for the explanation*

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware that these were all possible. In the end, you were right - refactoring to make async was the right thing to do.

Comment: Great explanation. I'm new to Rust, and I had this problem in a situation where my program was essentially a single threaded application, but the 3rd party software I used had an asynchronous API. The problem arose when I wanted to make a wrapper for the asynchronous stream that made it compatible with code expecting something implementing the `Read` trait. 

The "hack" of using `futures::executor::block_on(...)` would fix that for me, but your explanation makes it seem like I should avoid it all costs?

Comment: If your application is sync but you need to use an async library then using some form of `block_on` is fine. If your app is async, then using blocking the current thread is almost never fine. You have to take care when interacting with blocking code by using `spawn_blocking` or similar.

Comment: Can you have multiple block_on / spawn_blocking task even with a multi-threaded runtime? I could be wrong but I feel like I have two tasks trying to block_on (1 HTTP server, and then 1 route in that HTTP server needing to do async stuff) and it doesn't work well/I can't figure it out.