What is the recommended technique for calling an async function within a tauri protocol handler?
In order to call an async function within a Tauri protocol handler I'm successfully using futures::executor::block_on as described in the following SO answer. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66280983/4802953
But the answer discourages using this technique so I am not sure if this is the recommended way to call an async function from within a Tauri protocol handler.
A simplified version of my code is as follows:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .register_uri_scheme_protocol("myprot", move |_app, req| {
            let handle = tokio::runtime::Handle::current();
            let _guard = handle.enter();

            futures::executor::block_on(async move { handle_protocol_myprot(&req).await })
        })
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

If you can use Tauri 2.0 (currently beta), there's a new method register_asynchronous_uri_scheme_protocol that would let you have async call inside.

What's your end goal with the custom url scheme?

A demo app, a very limited web browser for a p2p network (Autonomi).

Then you'd probably be better off by running your local HTTP server and serving content on a local port.

I got the following response from FabianLars on the Tauri discord:

Tauri has an easier to use block_on function:
https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/async_runtime/fn.block_on.html (you
can import it and directly call it without the need for a handle
first). block_on is generally good enough if the task is not taking
too much time.
Speaking of handles, you have to give tauri one to your main tokio
runtime: https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/async_runtime/fn.set.html.
If you do not need to wait for the result to return from the protocol
handler you can of course use spawn instead.
If both of that doesn't work for you, v2 will have an async protocol
where you return the protocol from inside the spawned task:
https://docs.rs/tauri/2.0.0-beta/tauri/struct.Builder.html#method.register_asynchronous_uri_scheme_protocol
Ref: https://discord.com/channels/616186924390023171/1224053280565497896


Here's a piece from the underlying WRY library.
WebViewBuilder::new(window)
.unwrap()
.with_asynchronous_custom_protocol("wry".into(), |request, responder| {
  // here you can use a tokio task, thread pool or anything
  // to do heavy computation to resolve your request
  // e.g. downloading files, opening the camera...
  std::thread::spawn(move || {
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2));
    responder.respond(http::Response::builder().body(Vec::new()).unwrap());
  });
});

Also depending which platform you're on, some folks have been reporting issues with it.
