# Is there a way for Rust to use the default associated types?

Tags: rust

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924807/5884503 I'm adding associated types so I can return futures from my trait methods:

```
pub trait RtspClient: Runnable {
    type PlayResult: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), ()>>;
    type ConnectResult: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>;
    type DisconnectResult: Future<Output = std::result::Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>;

    fn connect(&self) -> RtspClient::ConnectResult {
        Ok(())
    }

    fn disconnect(&self) ->  RtspClient::DisconnectResult {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

However, the more methods I add, the more associated types I get.

This wouldn't be a problem, except that I need to specify all of them when I need to use `dyn RtspClient`:

```
  |
12 |     pub rtsp_client: Option<Arc<Mutex<dyn RtspClient>>>,
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated types: `RtspClient<PlayResult = Type, ConnectResult = Type, DisconnectResult = Type>`
   |
```

Is there a way to force rust to use the default ones I already wrote in the trait definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple misunderstandings here. The `Future<...>` part of the associated type is not a *default* it is a *constraint*. `Future` is not a type, its a trait. Its saying an implementation's `PlayResult`, for example, must satisfy the `Future<...>` constraint.

A *default* associated type would look like this:

```
pub trait RtspClient  {
    type PlayResult = Ready<Result<(), ()>>; // using std::future::Ready as an example
}
```

But this syntax is not yet stabilized:

```
error[E0658]: associated type defaults are unstable
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     type PlayResult = Ready<Result<(), ()>>; // using std::future::Ready as an example
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #29661 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29661> for more information
```

And even if you use a nightly compiler and enable the feature, you couldn't implement `connect()` and `disconnect()` by default because it must be valid for *all* possible implementations (you *can* do it in some cases, but I don't think this is one of them):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
12 |     fn connect(&self) -> Self::ConnectResult {
   |                          ------------------- expected `<Self as RtspClient>::ConnectResult` because of return type
13 |         ready(Ok(()))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `std::future::Ready`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<Self as RtspClient>::ConnectResult`
                       found struct `std::future::Ready<Result<(), _>>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:17:9
   |
16 |     fn disconnect(&self) ->  Self::DisconnectResult {
   |                              ---------------------- expected `<Self as RtspClient>::DisconnectResult` because of return type
17 |         ready(Ok(()))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `std::future::Ready`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<Self as RtspClient>::DisconnectResult`
                       found struct `std::future::Ready<Result<(), _>>`
```

And even if that did work, you'll have problems using it as a trait object. Each implementation can have a *different* concrete associated types, but you need to specify the concrete associated types to use it as a trait object. They will undoubtedly not match:

```
struct MyDefaultClient;

impl RtspClient for MyDefaultClient {
    // just uses the default types
    
    fn connect(&self) -> Self::ConnectResult {
        ready(Ok(()))
    }
    
    fn disconnect(&self) -> Self::DisconnectResult {
        ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

struct MyCustomClient;

impl RtspClient for MyCustomClient {
    type ConnectResult = Pending<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>; // different associated types
    type DisconnectResult = Pending<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>;
    
    fn connect(&self) -> Self::ConnectResult {
        pending()
    }
    
    fn disconnect(&self) -> Self::DisconnectResult {
        pending()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = [
        Box::new(MyDefaultClient) as Box<dyn RtspClient<ConnectResult = _, DisconnectResult = _>>,
        Box::new(MyCustomClient),
    ];
}
```

The `_` parts let the compiler infer the correct types, but will yield an error because `dyn RtspClient<ConnectResult = A, ...>` is different than `dyn RtspClient<ConnectResult = B>`.

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<MyDefaultClient as RtspClient>::DisconnectResult == std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>`
  --> src/main.rs:48:9
   |
48 |         Box::new(MyDefaultClient) as Box<dyn RtspClient<ConnectResult = _, DisconnectResult = _>>,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::future::Pending`, found struct `std::future::Ready`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>`
              found struct `std::future::Ready<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn RtspClient<DisconnectResult = std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>, ConnectResult = std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<MyDefaultClient as RtspClient>::ConnectResult == std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>`
  --> src/main.rs:48:9
   |
48 |         Box::new(MyDefaultClient) as Box<dyn RtspClient<ConnectResult = _, DisconnectResult = _>>,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::future::Pending`, found struct `std::future::Ready`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>`
              found struct `std::future::Ready<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn RtspClient<DisconnectResult = std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspDisconnectionError>>, ConnectResult = std::future::Pending<Result<(), RtspConnectionError>>>`
```

Associated types and trait objects do not mix in this fashion. You can think of them as regular generic types: `Struct<A>` is a completely different type from `Struct<B>`.

You should follow the other recommendations in the linked answer and use boxed futures, `Pin<Box<Future<...>>>`, or the helper crate `async-trait` instead of using associated types if you want to use different implementations interchangeably.