# Call async function in non-async for rustr

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, traits

Hi I have a system which pulls some data from different sources. All sources until today were sync so i designed the following API:

```rust
trait GraphPuller {
  pub fn Graph() -> Result<Vec<i64>>
}

struct GitPuller;
Struct TcpPuller;

impl GraphPuller for GitPuller {
  pub fn Graph() -> Result<Vec<i64>> {
  ...
  }
}

impl GraphPuller for Tc[Puller {
  pub fn Graph() -> Result<Vec<i64>> {
  ...
  }
}
```

Now I have to implement the Puller for AWS. AWS API is async, so i have to call async function in non sync system.

How Should I design the trait and api to avoid issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521201/how-do-i-synchronously-return-a-value-calculated-in-an-asynchronous-future-in-st) or the other way: [How can I define an async method in a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921581/how-can-i-define-an-async-method-in-a-trait)

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful to understand problem, however I had to block until future is returned and then return result, as interface i am describing is bigger than i show here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to keep the trait the same and to just block on the Amazon API calls. I'd recommend `pollster::block_on` because it implements just the very minimum instead of pulling in the more heavyweight `futures` crate.

Comment: Thank you It helped me. I did not refactore entire module, however We will think how to refactor it. I am not super familiar with Rust. I am still learning it, and I do not know all of its limitaitons.